# ActiveRecord: Is there a method to get the type of association between two classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Something like:

```
Post.association(Comment)
=> :has_many
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use *reflect_on_association*

```
Post.reflect_on_association(:comments).macro
```

Answer (score 0):

`Post.reflect_on_association(:comments).macro`